# What is the quote on how we cannot not choose (existentialism)?

Tags: existentialism, sartre

Okay, so some existentialist philosopher has said that we always choose. Even refraining from choosing is a choice. I think it was Sartre, but I am unable to find the exact quote (if there is one?). Can you guys help me with this?

Comment: It sounds like it's from Sartre's Existentialism is a Humanism: https://www.marxists.org/reference/archive/sartre/works/exist/sartre.htm .

Comment: based on heidegger's insistence that we are always doomed to die ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Thanks to virmaior for pointing out the text.)

There's a paragraph on this in *Existentialism is a Humanism*:

> First they tax us with anarchy; then they say, “You cannot judge
>   others, for there is no reason for preferring one purpose to another”;
>   finally, they may say, “Everything being merely voluntary in this
>   choice of yours, you give away with one hand what you pretend to gain
>   with the other.” These three are not very serious objections. As to
>   the first, to say that it does not matter what you choose is not
>   correct. **In one sense choice is possible, but what is not possible
>   is not to choose. I can always choose, but I must know that if I do
>   not choose, that is still a choice.** This, although it may appear
>   merely formal, is of great importance as a limit to fantasy and
>   caprice. For, when I confront a real situation – for example, that I
>   am a sexual being, able to have relations with a being of the other
>   sex and able to have children – I am obliged to choose my attitude to
>   it, and in every respect I bear the responsibility of the choice
>   which, in committing myself, also commits the whole of humanity. Even
>   if my choice is determined by no a priori value whatever, it can have
>   nothing to do with caprice: and if anyone thinks that this is only
>   Gide’s theory of the acte gratuit over again, he has failed to see the
>   enormous difference between this theory and that of Gide. Gide does
>   not know what a situation is, his “act” is one of pure caprice. In our
>   view, on the contrary, man finds himself in an organised situation in
>   which he is himself involved: **his choice involves mankind in its
>   entirety, and he cannot avoid choosing**. Either he must remain
>   single, or he must marry without having children, or he must marry and
>   have children. In any case, and whichever he may choose, it is
>   impossible for him, in respect of this situation, not to take complete
>   responsibility. Doubtless he chooses without reference to any
>   pre-established value, but it is unjust to tax him with caprice.
>   Rather let us say that the moral choice is comparable to the
>   construction of a work of art.

(My emphasis.)